# Hidden TextArea

Tags: html, css

In html for textbox it can be hidden by using `<input type="hidden" name="hide"/>` but for TextArea if I want to hide how should I use?

Anyone help me please,

Thanks,

Comment: style="display:none;"

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Set CSS `display` to `none` for textarea

```
<textarea name="hide" style="display:none;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks,but if I use like this it will not allow me to input the text into the textArea.

Comment: And if you use `type="hidden"` on a `input` it allows you?

Comment: Use Read Only in Text area.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_readonly.asp

Comment: @ankit suthar Read Only will just make it read only, not hidden as topickstarter ask.

Answer (score 25):

An `<input type=hidden>` element is not a hidden input box. It is simply a form field that has a value set via markup or via scripting, not via user input. You can use it for multi-line data too, e.g.

```
<input type=hidden name=stuff value=
"Hello
world, how
are you?">
```

If the value contains the Ascii quotation mark ("), then, as for any HTML attribute, you need to use Ascii apostrophes (') as attribute value delimites *or* escape the quote as `&quot;`, e.g.

```
<input type=hidden name=stuff value="A &quot;funny&quot; example">
```

Comment: Spike Williams is exactly right. That is why, when transferring textarea data, use a textarea. ...CSS display:none works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

but is the css style tag the correct way to get cross browser compatibility?

```
 <textarea style="display:none;" ></textarea>
```

or 
        what I learned long ago....

```
     <textarea hidden ></textarea>
```

or
    the global hidden element method:

```
    <textarea hidden="hidden" ></textarea>
```

Comment: The three of them work! 

Answer (score 3):

`<textarea name="hide" style="display:none;"></textarea>`

This sets the css `display` property to `none`, which prevents the browser from rendering the textarea.

Comment: I haven't slept in like 30 hours. Totally mis-typed.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
textarea{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```